# Spring Boot Jpa Kotlin - Not a Managed Type

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, jpa

I am getting the following error attempting to run my kotlin spring boot application.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class zielinskin.kotlinsample.data.SampleEntity
```

Trying to create a least possible code example repo with kotlin on the latest spring boot and kotlin, but am struggling. I am using OpenJDK 18.

I have tried with and without enable repositories annotation, Int and Integer for id, multiple types of entity scans (and without), but nothing seems to work.

Entity class:

```
@Entity
data class SampleEntity(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    var id: Integer? = null,
    var name: String
)
```

Configuration class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan(basePackageClasses = [SampleEntity::class])
@EnableJpaRepositories
class KotlinBootSampleApplication

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<KotlinBootSampleApplication>(*args)
}
```

Here is the repository and commit for reference:

https://github.com/zielinskin/kotlin-boot-sample

32d5cf311d455eb331b8ddefb9a116f43e662b1c

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue, using kotlin and Springboot, I solved it using `@EntityScan` and `@EnableJpaRepositories` annotations like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan("base.package.*")
@EnableJpaRepositories("base.package.*")
class BaseApplication
```

Comment: i will update my source and give it a whirl. I ended up "solving it" by reverting back to spring boot 2.5.7, but I don't see that as a legitimate solution

Comment: so it isn't working, with the exception that it can't find the entity still. here is some sample code:

https://github.com/zielinskin/kotlin-boot-sample/tree/feature/demonstrate-issue-with-entityscan

Comment: I've cloned your repo, I've changed springboot version to 2.7.2 and kotlin version to 1.7.10 as those are the versions I'm using, I had to add a spring:mvc:matching-strategy:ant_path_matcher configuration on application.yaml and it seems to be working, I'm using Java 11.0.16 from Amazon, could it be the version of Java you are using the problem? could you try with those changes I mentioned to see if it works for you?

Comment: would you be able to demonstrate via a fork on github or dm me? im only able to run on spring 2.5.7 to avoid getting swagger issues. or if you can also add in your fixes to the question, i will mark it as answered as soon as i get it working :)